# Why does Premiere Pro 6 Generate Peak Files?

Tags: premiere

I am having a challenge with Premiere Pro 6. Every time I open a project I get a little progress bar in the lower right hand corner of the window that says:

> Generating Peak File...

This can take a fair amount of time with a lengthy project. Is this normal? I have see comments on Adobe forums about issues with this.

Another possibly related issue is the project getting corrupted. Before I noticed this I tried making some changes while PP6 was Generating and ending up getting the dreaded project corruption message...

With that as background, is the Generating Peak File normal? What can I do about it and do I just need to be careful while it is going on not to make any changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peak file creation as well as creating alternate forms of various assets is perfectly normal background behavior for Premiere.  When you load new assets into a project, Premiere automatically starts a number of background processes to analyze the clip and make it easier for Premiere to do its job smoothly.

This should not cause any trouble and should not be a concern to you.  It is just the program functioning as it should.  It shouldn't cause any problems if you start working with it prior to completion of the work, but some functions may work more slowly or provide incomplete information while the processes are still going on.

Comment: AJ, thanks for the insights. Good to know things aren't going to blow up. Should it be doing this every time I resize the workspace window size?

Comment: @fmz - no, but sometimes it will redisplay the information about the background processing that is going on.  It doesn't seem to keep the display up all the time since it can sometimes be a time consuming operation.